# QGraphicsView antialiasing algorithm doesn't work well with very small details

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

the problem i had with QGraphicsView it shows images (Pillow generated images) with low quality that i can't read the text on image however i can see details better if i zoomed but on its full size it's not clear and very disappointing.

here is two samples one of the problem and one of wut it should be fixed to.

QGraphicsView scene quality problem

[image]

and this

same image opened from windows image viewer with same size:
link for sample: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWGnw.jpg

[image]

the code sample which will cover the issue.
font link: https://gofile.io/d/dXesZv

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore, QtMultimedia
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
import os

class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        #the image that would be viewed in QGraphicsView.
        _fnt = ImageFont.truetype("ar.ttf" , 100)
        _image = Image.new("RGBA", size=(2480, 3508), color="white")
        _draw = ImageDraw.Draw(_image)
        _draw.text((1000, 200), text="See See", fill="black", font=_fnt)

        #QGraphicsView ...
        _image.save("sample.png") ; os.startfile("sample.png") # to see what it should look like, like windows image viewer shows it.
        self.result = ImageViewer(self, _image)

        _layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        _layout.addWidget(self.result)
        self.setLayout(_layout)


class ImageViewer(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent, image):
        super(ImageViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        qim = ImageQt(image)
        self._pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
        self._photo = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(self._pixmap)
        self._scene.addItem(self._photo)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230)))

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.fitInView(self._photo, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        super().resizeEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximized)
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc i added a good code example, please take a look

Comment: Where do I get "ar.ttf"?

Comment: @eyllanesc i added the font link

Comment: @eyllanesc forgive me but i did try couple of fonts but same issue existed

Comment: @eyllanesc i guess it just can't be fixed under QGraphicsView i searched so hard for it, do you have any other way in mind to show image in widget with keeping aspect ratio and readability of text on image like windows image viewer other than QGraphicsView ?

Comment: You could set the [`renderHints`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#renderHints-prop) on the graphics view *and* the [transformation mode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicspixmapitem.html#setTransformationMode) to `SmoothTransformation`, but that might still present some artifacts for an image that big and details so small. An alternative might be to use a QLabel and use [`setPixmap()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop) using [`QPixmap.scaled()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaled) with `SmoothTransformation`, but I'm not really sure you'll get better results.

Comment: @musicamante as you said renderHints and transformation mode improved the scene but still same issue still there, i went for the 'big image' hint you mentioned so i gave up some resolution and made the 'PIL image' a bit smaller to be able to read text on it and it worked for now, thanks

Comment: @ahmed4end I suggest you to add your own answer to the question, explaining what caused the issue (the very high resolution), that using hints/transformation only partially solved the problem, and what you ended up doing to solve your problem.

Comment: @musicamante okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eventually I came up to kinda an answer to my question:

the issue was:

- QGraphicsView's performance with high resolution images is poor (can't read small details in image) as antialiasing algorithm doesn't work well with very small details.

what I tried, helped but never solved:

- I used .setTransformationMode(QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation) and .setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing | QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing) which helped.

what I gave away to solve it:

- I resized the high resolution image to a smaller resolution that can be viewed a good quality with the ability to read small details like small text.

how i resized the image:-

- the image used in the scene is a pillow object so i used the method .resize((int(image.size[0]/3.5), int(image.size[1]/3.5)), Image.ANTIALIAS), notice 1/3.5 ratio is optional.

Comment: How did you resize it? What options did you use? Also, you should either specify to what `setTransformationMode` and `setRenderHints` are applied, or, at least, set them as links to their documentation. Finally, the problem is not that QGraphicsView "can't read" small details, but that its antialiasing algorithm doesn't always work well with very small details (sharp contours with high contrast) in very high resolution images. Adding an answer to your own question is a good thing, but you also have to consider that other people might benefit from it, so they *must* have the right context.